# Крафтинг под Windows UDP/IP пакета в Qt-приложении, с установленным двайвером WinPcap

Tags: qt, сеть, ip, windowsinstaller, icmp

**В хакерских кругах циркулируют местами фрагментарные и небрежно изложенные сведения о технологии "супер-оружия" (выразимся так) для борьбы с `NAT`-ами всех видов и даже стоящими каскадом в любом количестве; равно как и с любого рода другими препятствиями для пиринговой связи - кроме одного, о котором скажу в конце.**

Технология несложна в понимании: допустим, X и Y могут узнать от `STUN`-а каждый свой внешний адрес, но этого им недостаточно для связи, т.к. оба сидят за двумя - в сумме четырьмя - `NAT`, к тому же симметрическими (таковые не пробиваются при помощи "подсказчика" `STUN`-а).. Что делать? Гнать трафик через `TURN` - будет либо медленно и тонкой струёй, либо небесплатно, да и во всех случаях небезопасно, плюс нужна чаще всего сложная аутентификация, создание аккаунта, привязка почты, телефона порой, заполнение анкет и т.п. - полюбуйтесь на это всё, например, у numb.viagenie.ca.. Туннелирование по `IPv6` редко-редко когда возможно, т.к. поддержка его мизерна, как вы можете убедиться, если имеете доступ к честной статистике.

Итак, как всё-таки быть? Вот собственно технология: клиентом X посылается запрос к любому не вызывающему подозрение сисадминов провайдера публичному ресурсу - google.com, mail.ru, fb.com и т.д., а в пакете посылаемом подменяется (спуфится) `IP` и `TTL`:

1. вместо `IP` клиента X им при отправке вписывается `IP` клиента Y,
2. время жизни пакета, `TTL`, выставляется микроскопическим, чтоб пакет *гарантированно* умер, не достигнув *ни одного из серверов вообще*,
3. когда пакет умрёт в двух шагах от точки старта, появится `ICMP`-пакет с траурным воплем о смерти оного - и послан будет он на... - нет, не туда, куда вы подумали - а послан он будет на тот адрес, который вписан был при отправке - то есть на `IP` клиента Y,
4. прибыв к клиенту Y, пакет-"похоронка" не просто расскажет адрес и порт того, кто его послал (эти `IP:порт` клиент X впишет в 16 байт payload'а запроса-камикадзе, а `ICMP` *обязан* по RFC своему повторить эти байты у себя в теле), а кроме подсказки ещё и "проторит путь" для последующей связи X и Y, наведёт `keep-alive`, так сказать.

И, как вы понимаете, если это делать нечасто, - а только лишь для "наведения мостов" в начале коммуникации X и Y, - то у сисадминов провайдера не будет никакого основания отрубить вам `ICMP`-трафик. Собственно только полное отрубание `ICMP`персонально вам и может обломать эту технологию. Всё остальное не способно ей противостоять.

ИТАК, ТЕПЕРЬ ПОЗВОЛЬТЕ ИЗЛОЖИТЬ СВОЙ ВОПРОС:

Я пишу на C++ Qt5.7 (QtCreator, MinGW, Windows 10 x64) приложение, реализующее тот функционал ,который я описал выше. Поскольку в Windows, после XP SP3, подмена адреса отправителя другим IP невозможна *без установки WinPcap*, то собственно вопрос такой - покажите, пожалуйста, как сделать две вещи:

- создать инсталлятор для Qt-приложения и в этом инсталляторе прописать установку `WinPcap` вместе с самим Qt-приложением, - разумеется, с повышенными привилегиями, т.е. от Администратора,
- как, подключив `WinPcap` в хедерах проекта, собрать (скрафтить) `UDP/IP` пакет-камикадзе, как я описал выше, с подмененным `IP`.

Answer (score 3):

Где вы только это вычитали. Больше не читайте таких ресурсов... Лучше возьмите грамотную книгу по строению сетей.

1. NAT - это не сетевой фильтр, а система подмены адресов. Если у провайдера NAT - значит реальников не хватает. А если так, то по какой бы вы технологии не отправили пакет на такой ip провайдер тупо не будет знать какому из клиентов его передавать. Ведь в основе любого NAT лежит запоминание устанавливаемых сессий. Вот вы отправляете пакет на гугл порт 443 со своего *внутреннего* ip (про подмену мы пока молчим) с порта 12345. Провайдер меняет ваш IP на некий из своего пула и меняет порт отправителя на 32000 и при этом запоминает, что любые пакеты пришедшие на порт 32000 от гугла (с того ip куда отправляли) надо отправлять клиенту X на порт 12345. Если снаружи придет пакет на любой другой порт, для которого такое состояние не было запомнено - то этот пакет будет уничтожен, так как не будет понятно кому его слать.
2. Любой мало мальски грамотный провайдер на сетевом фильтре первым делом блокирует *любые* пакеты пришедшие со стороны абонентов с *любыми* исходящими IP, которые не выдавались абоненту. Так что пакет с подмененным IP будет убит на первом же маршрутизаторе на пути (а в некоторых случаях прямо на свитче куда включен абонент). Да вдобавок к этому убит молча, без формирования ICMP. Таких блокировок нет только на межоператорских каналах (и то не всегда).
3. Понятие keep-alive существует только для протоколов с устанавливаемым соединением. Для ICMP пакетов такого понятия не существует. ICMP пакет физически не способен "проторить путь". Кроме случаев если этот ICMP является скажем запросом пинга и подпадает под общую схему NAT.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48457/discussion-on-answer-by-mike---windows-udp-ip---qt-).